# timeleft utility

Tags: c, datetime

This utility tells you how much time is left until the time you set before.

Setting time:

```
> timeleft set '2017/04/25;15:00:00'
```

Using utility:

```
> timeleft
2 days, 10 hours, 40 minutes, 25 seconds remaining...
```

Code:

```
#include <string.h> // strcmp
#include <stdio.h> // fopen, fclose, fprintf, fscanf, sscanf
#include <time.h> // time, mktime

#define TIME_PATH "time.txt"

static void printRemainingTime(time_t t) {
    const char *s = "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds remaining...\n";
    int days = t / 86400; t -= days * 86400;
    int hours = t / 3600; t -= hours * 3600;
    int minutes = t / 60; t -= minutes * 60;
    int seconds = t;
    fprintf(stdout, s, days, hours, minutes, seconds);   
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int status = 0;
    if (argc <= 1) {
        FILE *f = fopen(TIME_PATH, "r");
        if (!f) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open time\n");
            status = 1;
        } else {
            long t;
            if (fscanf(f, "%ld", &t) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not read time\n");
                status = 1;
            } else {
                time_t ref = (time_t) t;
                time_t now = time(NULL);
                if (now >= ref) fprintf(stdout, "It's over!\n");
                else printRemainingTime(ref - now);
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
    } else if (argc == 3 && strcmp(argv[1], "set") == 0) {
        int Y, M, D, h, m, s;
        if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d/%d/%d;%d:%d:%d", &Y,&M,&D,&h,&m,&s) != 6) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid time format\n");
        } else if (Y >= 2038) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Do not plan too far ahead!\n");
        } else {
            struct tm t = { s, m, h, D, M - 1, Y - 1900, -1, -1, -1 };
            time_t ut = mktime(&t);
            if (ut < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Parsing/range error\n");
                status = 1;
            } else {
                FILE *f = fopen(TIME_PATH, "w");
                if (!f) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to save time\n");
                    status = 1;
                } else {
                    fprintf(f, "%ld", (long) ut);
                    fclose(f);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ");
        if (argv[0]) fprintf(stderr, "%s ", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "[set YYYY/MM/DD;hh:mm:ss]\n");
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: `struct tm t = { s, m, h, D, M - 1, Y - 1900, -1, -1, -1 };` assumes a `struct tm` member order - which is not specified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. It doesn't compile without warnings under `clang -Wextra`:

   ```
   $ clang -Wall -Wextra cr161559.c
   cr161559.c:43:69: warning: missing field 'tm_gmtoff' initializer
         [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
               struct tm t = { s, m, h, D, M - 1, Y - 1900, -1, -1, -1 };
   ```
2. Expecting a semi-colon in the command-line arguments is inconvenient: it means that you always have to quote the argument when running the program from the shell:

   ```
   $ timeleft set 2017/04/25;15:00:00
   Invalid time format
   bash: 15:00:00: command not found
   ```

   It would be better to use some other input format, one that doesn't use shell meta-characters.
3. [Recommendation deleted following threat of violence in comments.]
4. Separating the declaration of `s` from the call to `fprintf` means that you won't get a warning (at least not from current versions of Clang or GCC) if the format string doesn't match the arguments. For example, if you accidentally omitted one of the arguments:

   ```
   const char *s = "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds remaining...\n";
   /* ... */
   fprintf(stdout, s, days, hours, minutes);
   ```

   then the compilation succeeds without warning under both Clang and GCC, but the output is nonsense:

   ```
   $ timeleft
   1 days, 22 hours, 33 minutes, 142630783 seconds remaining...
   ```

   But if you had written instead:

   ```
   printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds remaining...\n",
          days, hours, minutes);
   ```

   then Clang detects the problem:

   ```
   cr161559.c:12:45: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
       printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds remaining...\n",
                                              ~^
   ```

Comment: Beware, you may be bludgeoned to death with a giant 'S' for point 3 ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/237313

Answer (score 11):

Just a few suggestions:

**Standard Macros**

The file stdlib.h contains two macros that are very good to use when terminating the program, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. The might make `main()` a little more readable.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    if (argc <= 1) {
        FILE *f = fopen(TIME_PATH, "r");
        if (!f) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open time\n");
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            long t;
            if (fscanf(f, "%ld", &t) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not read time\n");
                status = EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else {
                time_t ref = (time_t) t;
                time_t now = time(NULL);
                if (now >= ref) fprintf(stdout, "It's over!\n");
                else printRemainingTime(ref - now);
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
```

**Put Each Statement on its Own Line**

This code might be more readable if each statement was on its own line:

```
static void printRemainingTime(time_t t) {
    const char *s = "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds remaining...\n";
    int days = t / 86400; t -= days * 86400;
    int hours = t / 3600; t -= hours * 3600;
    int minutes = t / 60; t -= minutes * 60;
    int seconds = t;
    fprintf(stdout, s, days, hours, minutes, seconds);   
}
```

Example:

```
static void printRemainingTime(time_t t) {
    const char *s = "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds remaining...\n";
    int days = t / 86400;
    t -= days * 86400;
    int hours = t / 3600;
    t -= hours * 3600;
    int minutes = t / 60;
    t -= minutes * 60;
    int seconds = t;
    fprintf(stdout, s, days, hours, minutes, seconds);   
}
```

**Compiler Warnings**

The compiler I am using is flagging the following lines for implicit type conversion from `long` to `int`:

```
    int days = t / 86400;
    int hours = t / 3600;
    int minutes = t / 60;
    int seconds = t;
```

Perhaps it would be better to declare `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` as `long` to match the same type as `t` can mutate to.

**Inconsistent Variable Naming Conventions**

In the function `printRemainingTime()` the code has the variables `t`, `s`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`. This is inconsistent. There are some good variable names such as `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` and then there are the variable names `t` (?time?) and `s` (?string?). Neither of these variable names are very descriptive. If `s` is for string, it might be better called `formatString` and if `t` is for time perhaps `inputTime` might be a better name.

Within the `main()` function there is the variable declaration `int Y, M, D, h, m, s;`. Perhaps more descriptive names would be `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`.

**Reduce Complexity, Follow SRP**

The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as follows:

> A class should have only one reason to change.

While this is primarily targeted at classes in object oriented languages it applies to functions and subroutines in procedural languages like C as well.

The main function could be broken up into at least 3 functions:

```
int getInputFromStdin(char outputStringReadFromStdi[])              // return EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE
int getInputFromFile(char inputFileName[], char outputStringReadFromFile[]) // return success 
void usage(char programName[]);             // prints the error message in the final else clause.
```

**The Error Message Isn't Quite Correct**

These two error messages don't use the complete filename of time.txt:

```
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open time\n");
```

and

```
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not read time\n");
```

The user could be mislead to add the file `time`, rather than the file `time.txt`

Answer (score 8):

- You don't really need `fprintf()` for printing to `stdout`; `printf()` does this by default and saves you an argument. You do still need `fprintf` for `stderr`, though.
- I think you are missing `status = 1;` for some of the `stderr`s in `main()`.
- If `t` is time-related, then you should declare it as a `time_t`. You can then cast it to a `long` in `fscanf` instead.
- This isn't consistent with your other condition formatting:

  > ```
  > if (now >= ref) fprintf(stdout, "It's over!\n");
  > else printRemainingTime(ref - now);
  > ```

  It should be:

  ```
  if (now >= ref) {
      fprintf(stdout, "It's over!\n")
  } else {
      printRemainingTime(ref - now);
  }
  ```

  There's also this:

  > ```
  > if (argv[0]) fprintf(stderr, "%s ", argv[0]);
  > ```

  which should be:

  ```
  if (argv[0]) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s ", argv[0]);
  }
  ```

Comment: One possible advantage of commenting which functions are used form an include is the following. When changing code, it becomes easier to remove unneeded includes.

Comment: "If `t` is time-related, then you should declare it as a `time_t`. You can then cast it to a `long` in `fscanf` instead."  --> `fscanf()` would need a `long *` cast not a `long` cast.  As `time_t` is not specified to be `long` that casting is problematic.  `time_t` is not even specified to be an integer.  Portable code cannot  `*scanf()` into `time_t` directly.  OP's approach has its short-comings like range, yet "cast it to a long in fscanf instead" is less portable.

Answer (score 6):

Since this has not been mentioned yet, this part is problematic:

```
else if (Y >= 2038) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Do not plan too far ahead!\n");
}
```

Firstly, hard-coding the date requires you to change your program in the future.

Secondly, why the limit at all? If it's a technical reason, you should tell the user. If not, it just limits the usefulness of the tool.

Comment: It's because of the [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). `time_t` could be either 32-bit or 64-bit integer, so in case it's 32-bit I'm limiting the range to year 2038. But I guess you're right and `mktime` would handle it internally just fine.

Comment: At the very least, don't use a magic number like `2038`. Use a named constant that happens to equal `2038`. Something like `const int kMaxYear = 2038;`.

Comment: The name `kMaxYear` has no value since it doesn't _explain_ what is going on here. A comment linking to the Wikipedia article would be more helpful.

Comment: @user1118321 UnixEpochEndYear is a better name.

Comment: @RolandIllig That's a fair point, but it's still better than a magic number with no context. At least with `kMaxYear` you have some idea that there's some limit, even if you don't know why. I agree with Taemyr that `UnixEpochEndYear` is better. It might be even better to have it calculated in code along the lines of calculating the time corresponding to `0xFFFFFFFF` and then pulling the year out of it.

Comment: I object. The name `kMaxYear` does not provide any value at all. First, the meaning of `k` is completely unclear. Second, the `max` part is already given by the combination of the `>=` operator and the following error message. And the `year` part is redundant because it is compared to the variable `Y`, which already means year, and it only makes sense to compare years with years. Therefore all parts of the name are redundant, and so is the name as a whole.

Comment: @RolandIllig I think a constant should have a name that explains it. So saying that `max` and `year` are redundant because of the context `Y >= ...` is a shaky proposition. On the other hand, even if `kMaxYear` is better than nothing, it's just not good enough, it needs more work. `UnixEpochEndYear` seems good enough.

Answer (score 3):

1. Let `mktime()` validate range.  The 2038 test is not needed as `mktime()` will report an error if the year is too great.

   ```
   //} else if (Y >= 2038) {
   //    fprintf(stderr, "Do not plan too far ahead!\n");
   //} else {
       struct tm t = { s, m, h, D, M - 1, Y - 1900, -1, -1, -1 };
       time_t ut = mktime(&t);
       if (ut < 0) {
   ```
2. Code assumes `time_t` is measured in seconds with `printRemainingTime(time_t t)`.  `time_t` is a scalar.  To portably convert to a *seconds* difference, use `difftime()`.

   ```
   double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);
   ```

   > The `difftime` function computes the difference between two calendar times: `time1 - time0`.  C11 §7.27.2.2 3
3. Other code assumes `time_t` is a seconds count bounded by `long` range like `long t; ... time_t ref = (time_t) t;` and `fprintf(f, "%ld", (long) ut);`.  At a minimum, code could use `long long` or `intmax_t` to cope with systems that use a wider than `long` time representation.  Highly portable code would use `double`, yet extra care is need to handle conversion issues.  Consider that the platform that writes the file may not be the platform the reads the file.
4. Code assumes the order of `struct tm`, which is not specified by C.  Could use below or [How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330793/2410359)

   ```
   // struct tm t = { s, m, h, D, M - 1, Y - 1900, -1, -1, -1 };
   struct tm t = {0 };
   t.tm_year = Y - 1900;
   ...
   t.tm_sec = s;
   t.tm_isdst = -1;
   ```
5. `"%d/%d/%d;%d:%d:%d"` with its `;` in the middle is a curious separator choice.   The [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) YMDhms format is more like `"2017-04-27T12:44:32"` yet that is not universal well known.  Code that could handle a variety of date formats (and with corresponding error detection) would be desirable.

   ```
    if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d/%d/%d;%d:%d:%d", &Y,&M,&D,&h,&m,&s) != 6) Good();
    else if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d", &Y,&M,&D,&h,&m,&s) != 6) Good();
    else if (sscanf(argv[2], Other formats, ...) != 6) Good();
    else Bad();
   ```
6. `sscanf(argv[2], "%d/%d/%d;%d:%d:%d", &Y,&M,&D,&h,&m,&s) != 6` allows input with trailing text like `"2017/04/27;12:34:56xyz"`.  A simple solution is to use `%n`

   ```
    int n
    n = 0; 
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d/%d/%d;%d:%d:%d %n", &Y,&M,&D,&h,&m,&s,&n);
    if (n > 0 && argv[2][n] == '\0') Good();
   ```
7. Nit: `if (ut < 0) {` is not the specified error condition. Highly portable code would use a test against `(time_t)(-1)`.

   > If the calendar time cannot be represented, the function returns the value `(time_t)(-1)`. C11  §7.27.2.3 3.
8. Nit: `int days = t / 86400;` can overflow 16-bit `int`, maybe in the year [3535](http://www.metrolyrics.com/in-the-year-2525-lyrics-zager-and-evans.html)